# Cumulative Geometric Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability

friends. I am learning about Cumulative Geometric Probability on Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/random-variables-geometric/v/cumulative-geometric-probability-greater-than-a-value. Here is the word problem:

Emelia registers vehicles for the Department of Transportation. Sports utility vehicles (SUVs) make up 12% of the vehicles she registers. Let V be the number of vehicles Emelia registers in a day until she first registers an SUV. Assume the type of each vehicle is independent.
Find the probability that Emelia registers more than 4 vehicles before she registers an SUV.

According to Sal Khan, 
P(registers more than 4 vehicles before she registers an SUV)=(1-0.12)^4. However, i have some doubts.

```
                         /\                        
                          0.88                  1st Vehicle is NOT SUV        
                           /\           
                            0.88                2nd Vehicle is NOT SUV        
                               /\                     
                                0.88            3rd Vehicle is NOT SUV        
                                   /\             
                                    0.88        4th Vehicle is NOT SUV         
                                       /\
  5th Vehicle IS SUV                0.12  0.88  5th Vehicle is NOT SUV
```

V: # of Vehicles registered NOT SUV UNTIL registering 1 SUV. So, when V=4, the 5th Vehicle MUST be SUV.

Now, Question ask for P(V=4 before registering 1 SUV). So the 5th Vehicle MUST be SUV.

Hence, the correct answer should be (0.88)^4*0.12. If it is (0.88)^5, it will mean that the 5th Vehicle is still NOT SUV, but the Question is asking for P(V=4 before registering 1 SUV) and NOT P(V=5).

Am i right to say that Sal forgot the *0.12? I would appreciate very much your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in your post as to whether this is $V>4$ or $V=4$. In the first instance the probability is $p=.88^5$ and in the second it is $p=.88^4*.12$.